# ZXing start BarcodeScanner portrait layout with IntentIntegrator

Tags: android, google-play, zxing

I would like to start BarcodeScanner in portrait layout (because my whole application is in portrait layout). 
I am also wondering, is it possible to install two applications at once from Google Play (you add some sort of dependency in manifest file to Barcode Scanner - which I am using in my application - and Google Play automatickly install Barcode Scanner alongside my application).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you require barcode scanning in Portrait I would suggest you incorporate the ZXing library into your application and make the approproate changes in order for it to work in Portrait mode.

Grab the source code here: [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

You are looking for the Android sample code in the library as well as the core.jar file to get the Barcode scanning going.

For instructions on how to get it working in Portrait just follow this: [Issue 178 - zxing - Running ZXing in Portrait](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178#c46)

I would strongly suggest reading the thread to get the background info on the change, but here is the basics of it:

> 1. In order to make screen work in portrait, set portrait orientation for the activity (e.g. in manifest) and then config the camera: Use
>      camera.setDisplayOrientation(90) in
>      CameraConfigurationManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(Camera camera).
>      But be aware that:
>
>    - setDisplayOrientation(int) requires Android 2.2
>    - setDisplayOrientation(int) does not affect the order of byte array passed in PreviewCallback.onPreviewFrame. (Refer to JavaDoc for
>        additional info)
> 2. Because preview frames are always in "landscape", we need to rotate them. I used clockwise rotation offered by comment #c11. Do not forget
>      to swap width and height parameters after rotation.
>      DecodeHandler.java, rotate data before buildLuminanceSource in
>      decode(byte[] data, int width, int height)
>
>    ```
>    rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
>    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
>        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
>            rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
>    }
>    int tmp = width; // Here we are swapping, that's the difference to #11
>    width = height;
>    height = tmp;
>    ```
> 3. I also modified CameraManager.java, getFramingRectInPreview(), as recommended by #c11:
>
>    ```
>    rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
>    rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
>    rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
>    rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
>    ```

The zxing library is quite easy to adapt in to your application to make it a more fluid and integrated user experience. highly recommended.

Comment: Hi this does not work. Even view is looking fine but did not detect Barcode

Answer (score 0):

Barcode Scanner does not support portrait layout, so you won't be able to do this. ([Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) does, but you can't depend on that being installed.) There is not a way to force another app to install from Market, no.

Answer (score 0):

Hi follow these steps to solve the portrait issue in Zxing Barcode scanner i tried and it is working fine ....

There are 4 relative files:

```
1, manifest.xml, you need to make CaptureActivity portrait.
```

2, DecodeHandler.java, rotate data before buildLuminanceSource, it works becuase in             YCbCr_420_SP and YCbCr_422_SP, the Y channel is planar and appears first

```
byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
 }
```

### 3, CameraManager.java, getFramingRectInPreview() need to be modified.

```
rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
```

4, CameraConfigurationManager.java, set camera orientation to portrait in setDesiredCameraParameters() use

```
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
```

and in getCameraResolution(), you need to swap x and y, because camera preview size is something like 480*320, other than 320*480.

```
int tmp = cameraResolution.x;
cameraResolution.x = cameraResolution.y;
cameraResolution.y = tmp;
return cameraResolution;
```

Comment: Barcode Scanner Support Portrait layout so we want to do the above modifications in the class files to support in portrait mode because i have done it and working fine... you use the Source code from zxing library https://code.google.com/p/zxing/